# Using grep on posixct vectors

Tags: r, posixct

I have multiple date-time columns and I need to verify which of them are in the timezone **CEST**

```
dat <- structure(c(1491199401.363, 1491201912.62, 1491205392.67, 1491205933.457, 1491206198.027, 1491206802.243), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")
dat
#[1] "2017-04-03 08:03:21 CEST" "2017-04-03 08:45:12 CEST" [3]
#"2017-04-03 09:43:12 CEST" "2017-04-03 09:52:13 CEST" [5] "2017-04-03
#09:56:38 CEST" "2017-04-03 10:06:42 CEST"

any(grep("CEST", dat))
#[1] FALSE
any(grep("CEST", "2017-04-03 08:03:21 CEST"))
#[1] TRUE
```

I can get this method to work if I copy/paste the elements into the `grep` function, but not if I run it on the vector itself. Using `as.character(dat)` does not work either. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can extract the time zone with `format` and use `%in%` to get the

```
"CEST" %in% format(dat, format="%Z")
#[1] TRUE
```

Or another option is to `unclass` after converting to `POSIXlt` and extract the `zone`

```
"CEST" %in% unclass(as.POSIXlt(dat))$zone
#[1] TRUE
```

---

In the single element that the OP was `grep`ping it is a `character` class while the `dat` is `POSIXct` class.  So, it will be able to find the substring using `grep`.  Even if, we convert the 'dat' to `character`, it will lose the attributes i.e.

```
as.character(dat)
#[1] "2017-04-03 08:03:21" "2017-04-03 08:45:12" "2017-04-03 09:43:12" "2017-04-03 09:52:13" "2017-04-03 09:56:38" "2017-04-03 10:06:42"
```

and therefore `grep` will not be able to pick it

```
grepl("CEST", as.character(dat))
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```